# FT232 Chip as UART to USB freezes windows and and access denied

Tags: atmega328p, ftdi, ft232

(Posting my own solution here)

I was trying to use a [FT232](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232R.pdf) to communicate with my Atmega328p-AU (arduino uno's MCU) and even though I had several times made this connection which worked fine, this time, when I try to connect to it using Tera Term, this error shows up:

[image: error access denied]

My connections are:

[image: UART to USB]

Comment: This means that the port doesn't exist or is taken by another program. It is not related to baudrate. It might be helpful if you could go to Windows device manager and post a screenshot of all the listed ports under "Ports". Anyway, this sounds like a PC problem and not an electronics problem.

Comment: Hm you might be right. But I was thinking it was a electronics problem, since I was thinking to ask people here if my layer stackup was correct etc. So I posted this here to help other people out.

Comment: Also, do you power the MCU from USB or from an external source? In case of the latter, you must connect signal grounds.

Comment: You are right. I was connecting signal grounds, I was powering it from USB, (But I had tried to power it with an external supply, and connect grounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was, I needed to un-select the "Divide by 8" fuse in the FUSES of the Atmega.

**NOTE/EDIT: Dividing by 8 the clock means all the computing inside the Atmega IC is slower (8 times slower), while when programming it, I "told it" it operates at 8Mhz, while its 1Mhz now. When I programmed the Atmega, I told it it has an clock frequency of 8Mhz, which is false, since this is divided by 8.
So the Baud rate (9600) which the Atmega was thinking it was using is wrong (Its 9600/8 now). Thats why the error its caused.**

[image]

But I still Do not understand why this would cause TeraTerm to show up a "Access denied" error

Comment: I think this answer is wrong. The fuse being wrong on AVR cannot possibly have an effect on the FT232 cause a program to open a serial port. It must be something else.

Comment: It must be something else yes. Changing the clock frequency of the mcu should not have anything to do with this error. But this solved my issue, since I never use this fuse. I Just forgot to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

An "Access denied" error on a COM port on windows is not related to the chip configuration or board. It is a windows error.

If the board had a problem either the port would not be there at all "Port not found" or it would be unable to communicate, but still able to open it (boards with an external USB serial chip).

It means that the port was already opened by another process and that the software could not access it, it sometimes happens if another software has opened the port, or the current software did not correctly close it.

Comment: Based on the solution I posted, you were eventually right, yes